# informix query to look for where is null when no record is found

Tags: sql, performance, null, informix

I want to write a query to return a result set based on a parameter I pass in,but if there are no matching records I want to return the result set where that parameter is null (the column I use in the where clause is nullable)

can I combine these two cases in one query ? is that better performance wise rather than having two separate queries executed.

```
execute select * from table where col_name is null
```

When I do not have anything returned for select * from table where col_name = $param)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is a conditional statement that i you can't validate before executing the first query, since you can't know for sure that the first is not getting you results until you run the query. So i would do the first query, and if no results were found, i would do the second one.

What you could do is:

Select both things, put the ones where col_name = $param at the top and only use the ones where col_name is null if you couldn't find the ones where col_name = $param;

```
select * from table where col_name is null OR col_name = $param
ORDER BY (col_name is null) ASC
```

This should give you the records with col_name = $param at the top and then the ones with col_name NULL. If the first record has col_name NOT NULL, it means that there are no records with col_name = $param.

Comment: thanks Filipe...hope this is not expensive than doing the if else in the scripting side and calling two sql even if it is cached

Comment: It's hard to tell without testing it. Do both of them and monitor the response times and see if you can see a real difference. If you can't see a difference, go with the one that makes your life easier :)

Comment: @SeanMshan. If you feel this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) on how that works)